# Fullscreen popupwindow is partial hide by status bar or virtual button

Tags: android, popupwindow

Fullscreen popupwindow is partially hiden by status bar, so that "offset" in y-axial is needed.

```
        PopupWindow mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(mLayout, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);
        //offset == status bar height
        mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(mContext, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, offset);
```

Problem is that if "offset" setted, on Nexus 4, bottom part of the fullscreen popupwindow is partially hiden by virtual buttons.

how to fix that ?